# Can you spoof your iOS to pair an Apple Watch with an older iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak, apple-watch, watchos

I'll keep it short, if an iPhone is jailbroken can you spoof your iOS version to pair an Apple Watch running OS 4 or 3 for iOS 10 on an iPhone with iOS 9.3.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apple Watch relies heavily on support from the phone for a lot of common tasks, especially features like cellular data, notifications, and iMessage. It’s possible there would be a way to spoof the version the watch sees, but without a few copyrighted frameworks from iOS 11 or 10, it’d probably crash before you finished pairing.